# Modify constructor of the class that all html elements inherit from to add event listener on them by default?

Tags: javascript, html

This is currently my code for an extension.

```
new MutationObserver((mutationRecords) => {
  mutationRecords.forEach((x) => {
    if (x.type === "childList") {
      x.addedNodes.forEach((x2) => {
        addListen(x2);
        if (x2.querySelectorAll) x2.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(addListen);
      });
    }
  });
}).observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
});

function addListen(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener("click", click);
}
```

Instead of doing this is there a way to modify the constructor of the class that all html elements inherit from to add event listener on them by default?

Edit: added details in the comments.

Comment: Why? Events bubble up the DOM (unless intercepted), hence a single event listener on the `<body>` would be enough.

Comment: I know but some of them can be stop propagation which would cause the click to go undetected.

Comment: The event listener also has to be the first event listener that is added to the element so that Event.stopImmediatePropagation() will not happen before.

Comment: I also want to do this by modifying the constructor of the class that all html elements inherit from because it would also work with shadow doms which observer would not unless the observer is put on ever shadow root.